# strip html - Whos job is it?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance

In db I have :  (**have** = existing situation. the DB has already has the data)

> Long html string (nvarchar max)

user have :

> asp.net  aspx page

mission:

> extract from the whole html string 1 specific sentence  - and show it to user

options :

1) do the strip job in sql and transfer the result to the client

`pros`: network is not loaded with the whole html - but the result

`cons` : sql server is working harder

2) send the whole html in the wire to the server and do the job there.

`pros` : sql is not working too hard  , iis do the job with ready-tools ( html agilitypack)

`cons` : network wire is loaded with unwanted data

**which approach is the right one ?**

p.s.

lets assume that the hardware is excellent.

Comment: T-SQL is very bad at string parsing. Definitely put this process elsewhere.

Comment: @Yuck I can use  a ready dll  - enable clr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to retrieve this specific piece of data repeatedly you should store it separately - in another column on the same table, for example.

When saving the HTML, extract this piece of information for storage (also on update, to ensure that the information stays in sync).

I would suggest using an HTML parser like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse and query the HTML and doing it in the ASP.NET code that will save to the DB instead of doing it in the DB (as string manipulation does not have great support in databases).

This has the benefit of only retrieving the data when you need it and processing only when required.

Comment: I cant seperate it while saving . lets say its an existsing scenario where the data is already in DB ( 1 column  - html column).

Comment: @RoyiNamir - since you say you have SQL/CLR, see if you can get the [HAP](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) into SQL Server and use it there to extract the data. Ideally, find a way to pre-compute and store it.

Comment: Can I assume (from your answer) that the DLL for sql for HAP is the idle solution ?

Comment: yes, parse the data during the write. this will greatly improve the throughput for reads.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - I gave you my options for ideal... I think that using the HAP in SQL is better than incurring network IO. You really need to test both approaches in your situation to see what will perform best.

Answer (score 0):

Its always good to go for loss-less data storage.. because it could be useful in future.. i think 2nd option is good, you should save html in db and use agilitypack to parse the data.. as you have mentioned the hardware is excellent agilitypack should do its work easily because it works on principles of xml document that is quite faster to traverse nodes.

Regards.

Comment: isnt the first rule in sql is : **get only what you need** ?

Comment: yes it is. but if only one sentence is you target in the whole html. and you will never need the source you should extract it and save to db. you really need to create balance in what data you need and how much processing you can afford to get the desired results. one time processing while saving to db. or on demand when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I would also go with HTML Agility Pack option only.

That said, if the HTML stored in the DB is well formed and you are using SQL Server 2005+ then try out this to see if it helps - http://vadivel.blogspot.com/2011/10/strip-html-using-udf-in-sql-server-2005.html